# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, nltk

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'translate'

```
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT content FROM news_tb")
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for row in myresult:
    row = row.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower()


    tokens = word_tokenize(row)
    listStopword = set(stopwords.words('indonesian'))
    wordsFiltered = []

    for t in tokens:
        if t not in listStopword:
            wordsFiltered.append(t)
    print(wordsFiltered)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Rahmadyan/PycharmProjects/Skripsi/nltk_download.py", line
>   17, in 
>       row = row.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)).lower() AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no
>   attribute 'translate'

Comment: I take it you are expecting a different object from `myresult` than the tuple you are getting. I would check to see `print(row)`, `print(row[0])` and `print(row[1])` inside your `for row in myresult:` loop

Answer (score 1):

Even though it is only returning a single column it still puts the value into a tuple just like it would if multiple values were returned.

Each row in the value is going to be something like `("hello",)`

To get the string you'll need to access it like this `row[0]`